# Only rotate ActionBar and preserve other views

Tags: android

Is it possible when a device is rotated to only rotate the ActionBar and leave the views untouched.

My use case is a simple drawing app where the content should not be rotated but the chrome of the UI (ie the ActionBar) should be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have basically two options:

1. When the device is rotated, store away enough information (see [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)) so that you can restore your app's view(s) in such a way as to make it appear to the user as if nothing has changed.
2. Set your activity to ignore rotation configuration change events and then do absolutely everything manually (see [`onConfigurationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)).

Personally, I think you will find it much less frustrating to figure out an appropriate way to use option 1 rather than having to deal with the much more complicated option 2.